# Partial RegExp match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a JavaScript input key validator. I want to use regular expressions for this purpose. When user presses a key - input text field is checked that his value satisfy some regular expression, and if it isn't then user input is rejected.

Is it possible to catch a match when regular expression matches only part of expression?

Just for better understanding of question:
Regular expression: `([0-9]{3})([0-9Xx]+)`

```
"" matches
"0" matches
"01" matches
"01c" not matches
"014" matches
"0149" matches
"0149x" matches
"0149xD" not matches
"0149xDX" not matches
"0149xX" matches
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([0-9]{0,2}|[0-9]{3}[0-9Xx]*)$
```

Comment: it is only single case... i need a reusable solution which will work for any expression

Comment: The main thing here is to anchor your expression using `^(...)$` so the entire string will always be checked. This works for any expression. Everything else has to be adapted to the actual rules of allowed and disallowed matches.

Answer (score 0):

Why not having a one regular expression for text being edited and another for the final text. So if you can specify what text is appropriate as a "half input" you can master a regex for it.